# document.getElementById for select tag gives object error in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a `select` tag in my HTML and  in Internet Explorer, when it is called from a JavaScript function an error occurs.

This is the html creates the select box-

```
 <select id="item1" name="Item 1" onchange ="fn();">  
    <option value="0">Please select gender</option>    
    <option value="1">Male</option> 
    <option value="2">Female</option>  
 </select>
```

function for onchange event of select-

```
function fn()
{   
    var s = document.getElementById('item1');  
    if(s!= null)  
    {  
       alert('not null')  //if object not == null  
    }  
}
```

This is the error I am getting in IE -

```
Message: Object expected
```

Comment: In IE 8 I get "not null". Are you sure that's exactly what you are running? Strictly, you should probably have `=== null` but it makes no practical difference here.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have anything else wrong on the page (for example, another tag with the same ID)? "Object expected" is one of the most common IE errors. You should consider posting your full code for us to examine.

Comment: try giving it identical `id` an `name` values.

Comment: @Reshma what you changed ?

Comment: that was  an error before this statement that caused all these problems. thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you get the domNode, if it already fires the function? Wouldn't the `onChange` could not get fired at all, if the domNode would be `null` (didn't exist)?

How about this:

**HTML**

```
    <select id="item1" name="item1" onchange ="fn(e);">  
       <option value="0">Please select gender</option>    
       <option value="1">Male</option> 
       <option value="2">Female</option>  
    </select>
```

**JS**

```
    function fn(event) {
       // FF, Safari etc..
       if(event.target) {  
           alert('fn() fired by ' + event.target.id)
       }
       // IE
       else if(event.srcElement) {
           alert('fn() fired by ' + event.srcElement.id)
       }
    }
```

Comment: Read the OP. Calling `getElementById` isn't returning `null`, it's throwing an error. The code as posted "works" in IE, there is some other issue.